# Spring DATA REST JSON mapper to Domain Model

Tags: json, jackson, gson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the problem, I am using Spring Data Rest. So i have some Domain Model like this:

```
@Entity
public class Sample implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_main")
    private Boolean isMain;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    private Date lastModified;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,name="state_id")
    private SampleState state;
}
```

So from client I am sending POST request to http://{server.host}:8080/samples
to create Sample with JSON:

```
{"name":"sample","user":{"id":1},"state":{"id":1}}
```

Hoping that it will automatically map "user" of json to Model param "user", but HttpMessageConverter just ignore the "state" JSON Object and "user" Json Object. Can you help how can I manage to Customize converter or any other ways to create sample?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In spring-data-rest such questions depend heavily on how your repositories are configured. Do you have repositories for `User` and `SampleState`? Are these repositories exported?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by **ignore**?

BTW, if you have 'user' and 'state' objects with the 'id' value '1'; then the association should persisted with new sample object successfully in the database.

But if you want to create the whole object graph into db, then the id value should be null and perhaps you might need to setup the proper cascade options.